# Finding angular frequency via integration of Newton's Second Law for a physical pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators, calculus

For context: I am a student enrolled in AP Physics C with prior knowledge from AP Calculus AB and AP Physics 1.

We just collected data for a lab to determine an experimental value for g. The setup involves a meter stick rotating about its end and a movable mass (see diagram below).

[image: Meter stick and mass setup]

We collected data for the mass of the meter stick and the movable mass, the length of the meter stick, the location of the mass for each trial, and the total time for 10 complete oscillations.

The ultimate goal was to derive an equation for angular frequency $\omega$ (and by extension, period $T$). I started by finding the moment of inertia for the system.

$$I=I_{stick}+I_{mass}=\frac{1}{3}M_sl^2+M_mR^2$$

Then, a formula for the net torque on the system.

$$\tau=Fr\sin\theta$$

With $F=mg=(M_s+M_M)g$, the small angle approximation $\sin\theta=\theta$ for $\theta<15°$, and center of mass $d$:

$$\tau=(M_s+M_m)gd\theta$$

From here, we're directed to derive angular frequency ($\omega$) from the equation $\tau=I\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}$. My attempt looked like this:

$$\tau=I\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}$$
$$\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}=\frac{\tau}{I}$$
$$\int{d^2\theta}=\int{\frac{\tau}{I}dt^2}$$
$$\omega=\int{\frac{(M_s+M_m)gd\theta}{\frac{1}{3}M_sl^2+M_mR^2}}dt^2$$

And I get stuck here. I know that the big fractional term is a constant, none of those variables (except $\theta$) change with time. I could pull that out, substitute the equation for center of mass $d$, and rewrite as

$$\omega=\frac{(M_s+M_m)g\left(\frac{M_s\frac{l}{2}+M_mr}{M_s+M_m}\right)}{\frac{1}{3}M_sl^2+M_mR^2}\int{\theta}dt^2$$
$$\omega=\frac{\frac{1}{2}g\left(M_sl+2M_mr\right)}{\frac{1}{3}M_sl^2+M_mR^2}\int{\theta}dt^2$$

but this doesn't get me any closer to the actual solution:

$$\omega=\sqrt{\frac{mgd}{I}}$$

I've tried looking at derivations for simple pendulums, but that hasn't really helped me yet. I might just be missing a link somewhere.

Comment: If $d^2 \theta / dt^2 = f$ , then that does not mean you can write $\int d^2 \theta = \int f dt^2$. The second derivative $d^2 y/dx^2$ does not come from the limiting value of the fraction $(\Delta y)^2 / (\Delta t)^2$, unlike the first derivative. Which is why you can only do what you did with first derivatives, roughly speaking. Also your torque equation is missing a minux sign. Look for derivations for the physical pendulum. The general idea is still the same. Cast your equation into the form of the SHM equation $\ddot{x} = - \omega^2 x$ and you're done.

Comment: Your third equation appears to have inconsistent units.  I don't know if that affects anything.

Comment: Related : [Need help understanding an equation of motion for a pendulum](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/599890/need-help-understanding-an-equation-of-motion-for-a-pendulum/599916#comment1563654_599916).

Comment: What is the difference  between r and R ?

Answer (score 1):

Given the two equations for the torque (one with the angular acceleration, $\mathrm d^2\theta/\mathrm dt^2$ and one with the gravitational force), you combine them as,
$$ \frac{\mathrm d^2\theta}{\mathrm dt^2}=\frac{\tau}{I}=-\frac{mgr}{I}\sin\theta $$
where the minus sign comes because the force is restoring (i.e., opposes the motion). Under your small angle approximation, this becomes,
$$ \frac{\mathrm d^2\theta}{\mathrm dt^2}=-\frac{mgr}{I}\theta $$
This equation is an ordinary differential equation that is commonly seen in physics. To solve it, we want to express it in the form $\mathrm d^2\theta/\mathrm dt^2=-\omega^2\theta$ which would directly give us your wanted result:
$$ \frac{\mathrm d^2\theta}{\mathrm dt^2}=-\frac{mgr}{I}\theta =-\omega^2\theta\Rightarrow\omega^2=\frac{mgr}{I}\Rightarrow\omega=\sqrt{\frac{mgr}{I}}$$
So you don't actually need to solve the ODE that you are given, you just need set it up so that your terms are correctly aligned.

Comment: As an aside, the [Wikipedia entry on the Pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mechanics)) contains the derivation of the ODE from forces, torques and energy formulations, as well as the solution from the small angle approximation. It would be worth your time to read through; if you don't understand something there, feel free to ask a new question about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a differential equation like $f''(t)=-A*f(t) $ you should remember, that $(cos(at)'=-asin(at)$ and $(cos(at))''=-a^2cos(at)$  same for sin so the solution is $$f(t)=C_1sin(\sqrt{A}t)+C_2cos(\sqrt{A}t) $$
Maybe you should learn something of simple differential equations.

Comment: This is an awfully rude way to answer a question.