# Why is it always $\psi= A \sin kx + B \cos kx$ to solve a wave function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, complex-numbers

Why is it always $\psi= A \sin kx + B \cos kx$ to solve a wave function instead of the one with $e^{ikx}$? Both are the solutions but the one with $e^{ikx}$ is seldom used.

Comment: Seldom used?  Not in my experience. The exponential form $e^{\pm ikx}$ is simpler, and almost always used in the books I learned waves from.

Comment: Related : [Need help understanding an equation of motion for a pendulum](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/599890/need-help-understanding-an-equation-of-motion-for-a-pendulum/599916#comment1563654_599916).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply, the difference between the two versions of that solution is just that one is real while the other is complex.  If you're trying to model — say — the position of a mass on the end of a spring, that position is a real number, so you just don't need a complex number.

However, I would disagree with the premise that the $\sin$-$\cos$ version is used "always" and the other "seldom".  In fact, as you get to more advanced physics, $e^{ikx}$ is almost always the one you use.  This is partially just because it's easier to remember how to manipulate exponents than to remember trig identities when manipulating the solution, and you just take the real part at the end of the process to represent the physical behavior.

Moreover, in quantum mechanics you essentially *always* use  $e^{ikx}$, because the wavefunction is actually complex.  I notice that you tagged the question with "quantum-mechanics" and "schroedinger-equation".  I don't think I've ever seen a $\sin$-$\cos$ solution used in these scenarios.  (Technically, you *could* use it, if you assume $A$ and $B$ are complex, but there would be a lot of extra work to do, so nobody does it that way.)